# Technique for getting rid of the catch-all route in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I just took over a Rails 3.0 project that is making use of the dreaded catchall route: `match '/:controller(/:action(/:id))'`. I'd like to get rid of it and replace it with proper defined routes. However, there are a large number of controllers and I want to make sure to do it without breaking anything, so I need to audit the project to see which controller actions are relying on the catch-all. Is there any tool or method to check all of the controllers to see which actions hit that particular routes.rb entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem about a month ago.  There is no easy answer that I know of, especially if it is a poorly tested application.  The best method I found was:

1. Remove the black hole route.
2. Run `rake routes` and compare against each of my controllers.
3. Test everything I could find having to do with that controller and add in the missing routes where needed.
4. Repeat.

Best of luck to you.